# Apache camel Jetty component access logs

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jetty

I am having a spring boot application which uses apache camel jetty component for routes. My requirement is to log every incoming request details for this route. The way tomcat access logs are logged in files which contains IP, host, uri etc., in the similar way, I have to log the camel jetty logs into the file. I searched a lot on google but no luck.
Please provide solution which can help me in getting access logs enabled for camel jetty component.

Comment: Jetty calls it the `RequestLog`, it's a Server level component, and can be configured in numerous ways (even customize the output if your are running a more recent version of Jetty).  No idea how to configure it within Camel.

Comment: Hi Joakim, Thanks, This helped me in configuring log in camel Jetty Component.